# Apache Pig vs Hive

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

i'm new in big data , my company is a big data warehouse i want to make some BI and analysis on big data 
i use hbase and hadoop

which best for making analysis and online reports , Hive or Pig?

Answer (score 4):

Look in this discussion:
[Difference between Pig and Hive? Why have both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356259/difference-between-pig-and-hive-why-have-both/6924095#6924095)

In a nutshell - Hive is declarative -you actually write SQL, while Pig is imperative - you write execution plan.
I think Hive is easy to jump-start especially if you familiar with SQL, while Pig will give you more flexibility.