# Scenorios where Pig can use not Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

I am writting decision analysis report. I would like to know the scenorios where Pig can use but not hive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Pig and Hive? Why have both?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356259/difference-between-pig-and-hive-why-have-both)

Answer (score 0):

There is a free, training video provided by Cloudera which clearly explains your scenario.
Find the link [here](http://cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/resources/library/training/cloudera-essentials-for-apache-hadoop-webinar-series-4-of-6-getting-to-know-the-components-of-the-apache-hadoop-ecosystem.html).

Comment: Please provide a summary of the video.