# Diff between hive with tez and pig with tez

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, tez

I want to know the difference btw hive with tez and pig with tez. why in hive with tez numbers of maps and reducer used can be seen in the console but in pig we can see only number of tasks launched. why

How to calculate reducers launched in pig with tez...........

How to calculate reducers launched in hive with MR.

Based on the default configuration i believe that number of reducer launched in hive with MR is based on the data size

when i did distinct operation in Hive with MR it uses 3 Mapper and 7 reducer
the data size was just 426 MB. and the job ran as a single job.

How reducers are calculated in Hive with MR, Hive with Tez, PIg with Tez/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Pig and Hive? Why have both?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356259/difference-between-pig-and-hive-why-have-both)

Comment: Your question was already put on hold as too broad here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40664322/2573061 . Please edit your original question.